# Boilerpipe Server Error when trying to extract url content

Tags: internal-server-error, boilerpipe

I'm trying to use boilerpipe to extract the content from a given url. When I try the demo ui it returns a server error:
[Demo window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS5Gm.png)

The same error is returned when making the call to the api. Does anyone have the same problem? Can it be related to the API key (If yes how to acquire one?).